# How to port forward between two routers?

Tags: router, ip, port-forwarding, ip-address

Here's what I exactly need:

I have my landlord's Modem-Router which is the cable internet modem, the main router which connect us to internet / I call it Router 1 which is "192.168.1.1"

And I have my room's router / I call it router 2 which is "10.0.0.1"

I want to setup VPN on Router 2

And it seems that the VPN port should be first opened on Router 1 - as far as I know I should port forward Router 1 to router 2 (Which is VPN server)

But I have a problem. Router 1 doesn't accept a different IP range!

How do I port forward VPN traffic from Public IP Address to Router 2?

Pleas Note that I don't want to make my Router 2 bridge or disable DHCP. I want to have a separate network from Router 1 and still forward incoming VPN traffic from internet to Router 2.

Thanks already for your help!

Comment: If you use a software VPN, all the traffic to and from your PC will be encrypted, and you will not need to worry about a VPN on your router.

Comment: @K7AAY if I understand the question correctly, they want to setup a VPN server through router 2 and be able to connect to it from the internet.

Comment: What VPN protocol?  You may nit need to do anything on router1 depending on protocol.

Comment: Are you wanting router2 to be a client or server?

Comment: my router 2 is going to be a server. I am getting error: "Invalid IP address" when trying to port forward internet traffic through internal IP address of my Modem-Router1 "192.168.1.1" to Router2 "10.8.109.221". And I my Router2 doesn't allow me to change it's IP to range 192.168.x.x, what should I Change?

Answer (score 1):

Your router 2 will also have a public IP address, which is in the range on Router 1. Use that ip address to setup your portforwarding if you setup the routers correctly by cabling.

Here's how the cabling should be done:

```
 [internet] -> [wan port on router 1]
               [lan1] [lan2] [......]
                 |       |
 [Landlord pc] <-+       +-> [Router 2's WAN port]
```

Lets say, the internet WAN IP is 123.45.67.89. This goes into the WAN port on Router 1.

Router 1 has the internal network 192.168.1.x with DHCP enabled for the range 50 to 150

The landlord's PC has IP: 192.168.1.50 (first in the DHCP range)
Your router gets IP: 192.168.1.51

Your router gives out DHCP for its network for 10.0.0.x

Even though you setup your router to have the ip address 10.0.0.1, it also has 192.168.1.50 for the WAN IP address.

So on router 1, you have to figure out through the DHCP clients table which LAN IP your router2 has given. Once you do, make sure you make a DHCP reservation so ensure that if you reboot router 2 it will not get a new and different ip from router 1 which would break it sportforwarding rules.

You can then port forward the proper ports on router 1 to that ip address. If you have ports that need to be forwarded to your pc from the internet, you have to do the same thing. Forward that port from router 1 to the LAN address of router 2, and on router 2, you setup a port forwarder rule to your LAN PC.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. But My router 1 only accepts port forwarding to the same IP range ex: "192.168.1.x" not the public ip addresses. and how do I find public ip address of router 2? because wether I use R1 or R2 or any device on network they all give me same IP address.

Comment: @Isaac not just your router, every router does this. That's the nature of routers. But your statement suggests you do not understand my answer. So let me try to clarify, You forward ANY port FROM the public ip TO one of the internal ip's. That's why you get to only select the 192.168.1.x range.

Comment: In order to get the WAN ip address of R2, login to admin interface of R2 and look at the status page for its WAN ip address.

Comment: Also keep in mind that all ip addresses of R1 are 192.168.1.x and they are internal ip addresses for R1, whereas the one assigned to R2 will be R2's public ip address.

Comment: R2 is just giving me private / local ip address of "10.8.109.221" . everything on the network including PCs are getting same public address of R1, even device connected to R2.